# jqGrid: confirm dialog before submit in inline editing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How can I show a custom confirm dialog after user press ENTER after inline edit, before submit to the server?
I found similar old questions here (2010/2011), but maybe there are new functions/events to solve this.

I need to give the user the chance to read some alert, and decide to SAVE or CANCEL edition.

NOTE: I know how to use ui.dialog, that's not my question. It's about jqGrid events callbacks. Thanks!

(my version is Free jqGrid 4.13.7-pre)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - or ask here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) we have added two events in editRow (inline editing method) [onEnter and onEscape](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ac45e12894f5862e6087ec67ea61cd7f77c1c191)

This way it is possible to call your own pop up window and use saveRow or/and restoreRow methods on condition.